# How do I jump to a topic in vim under Terminal for a French Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, macvim, internationalization

I'm on a French keyboard and I'm unable to jump to a topic in vim: If I go ':help' the instructions say:

> Jump to a subject:  Position the cursor on a tag (e.g. |bars|) and hit
>   CTRL-].

I've tried various combinations with no luck. For example ALT+SHIFT+) gives ']' but adding CTRL does not work.

The only hack I found was to map CTRL-L to CTRL-] by add this to .vimrc:

```
map <C-l> <C-]>
```

Are there perhaps special mappings for French keyboards in Vim or Mac + French keyboards?

Comment: Darn, typo in question. Can someone please fix it for me since I do not have the rights yet. Thanks!

Comment: Same thing with a finnish keyboard (perhaps any keyboard where producing ] requires alt?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, seems the answer is:

> The only hack I found was to map CTRL-L to CTRL-] by add this to
>   .vimrc:
>
> ```
> map <C-l> <C-]>
> ```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to waste your CTRL-L, you can make CTRL-***"] key"*** work like this:

```
:map CTRL-VCTRL-"] key" <C-]>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well on a Mac French keyboard, I just press CTRL+$ (the */$/€ key is the one located to the left of the return key)

Answer (score 2):

I Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> on my Spanish keyboard.

Comment: CTRL+5 Works on my Danish Mac keyboard as well.